# Bind JavaScript Equality Operator to Java Function

Tags: java, javascript, scriptengine

I am using the JavaScript Engine in Java to evaluate some strings. I want `user.group == group1` in JavaScript to evaluate the Java method `user.hasGroup(group1)`. User contains a list of group strings.

I know I can bind functions with the following, but I am not sure how to replace the equality operator and use the right side as a parameter. (jsEngine is my JavaScript engine)

```
Bindings b = jsEngine.createBindings();
b.put(String name, Object value);   
Engine.setBindings(Bindings bindings, int scope);
```

Comment: wow, a question which is legitimately about `[java]` and `[javascript]` ;)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. I think the best you could do, in some cases, would be something along these lines: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4700278/636009 but there's nothing you could translate `user.group` and `group1` to that would show them as equivalent under string comparison, is there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsEngine.eval("if(user.group == group1)")`, catch the Boolean object and decide further.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are you suggesting that I evaluate the boolean before I define what `user.group` is?

Comment: No, you create the binding with the user data first. I am only saying based on `jsEngine.eval("if(user.group == group1)")` , you take some actions in java or javascript, based on your implementation.

Comment: I think what I want is not possible, so I opted to use `user.hasGroup(group1)` explicitly.