# In Javascript, why does [1,2] == [1,2] resolve to false?

Tags: javascript

I am storing (x,y) coordinates as 2-element arrays.

```
var coordinateA = [0,3];
var coordinateB = [1,2];
```

I also have a longer array containing many of these coordinates:

```
var coordinates = [coordinateA, coordinateB]
```

Imagine my surprise when the following statements turned out to be false:

```
jQuery.inArray(coordinateA, coordinates); // returns -1
coordinateA == coordinates[0];            // returns false
[0,3] == [0,3];                           // returns false(!)
coordinateA == coordinateA;               // returns true, thankfully
```

Could someone help me understand why this is the case? Also, is there a better way to represent 2D coordinates in Javascript? Thanks for any clues or suggestions.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700085/can-i-define-custom-operator-overloads-in-javascript) for an alternative

Comment: Comparing two objects determines if they are the same object, the content is not compared.

Comment: Actually, if you set the coordinates array the way you have described, it should work as you expect (the element at `coordinates[0]`, and `coordinateA` *shoud* point to the same memory). I have a feeling the issue is somewhere else, or is browser-dependent (just confirmed it works as expected in chrome)

Comment: Think of references in JS as pointers. If you have 2 `char* a, *b`, would you compare its content with `a == b`?

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have two separate array **references**.

The equality operator is checking that the references are equal, not the content of the arrays.

Comment: This holds for empty arrays too. Just in case someone is wondering.

Answer (score -1):

One of the puzzling things about JavaScript is how equality is dealt with. I will do my best to explain this.

The equality rules can be quite hard to grasp. Generally speaking, you can compare by relative equality (`==`) or strict equality `(===)`.

**relative equality**:

This compares by value only and does not care about type.

Example

```
var x = '2';
var y = 2;
x == y;
=> false;
```

In relative equality, the string `"2"` equals the number 2. This will return true since types are not compared

**strict equality**

This compares by both value and type.

Example

```
var x = '2';
var y = 2;
x === y;
=> false
```

In this case, the string `"2"` does NOT equal the number 2. Because String and Number are two different types.

Comparisons with arrays and objects are done differently though.

In your case, arrays are considered objects.

```
typeof([1,2])
=> "object"
```

In JavaScript, all objects are different. They are compared by their object ids. To determine if arrays are equal, you have to perform `type conversion` to a string.

```
String([1,2]) == String([1,2])
=> true
```

However, the `underscore` library has an `is_equal` method that can determine whether two arrays are equal

```
_.isEqual(array1, array2);
```

Underscore does this by performing a `deep comparison` between two objects to determine if they should be considered equal.

It's important to note that order matters here, as it does in the string comparison.

```
_isEqual([1,2], [1,2])
=> true

_isEqual([1,2], [2,1])
=> false
```

Comment: *"relative equality - Compares by value only and does not care about type."* That's just not true. Both `==` and `===` care very much about type, and in fact the `==` cares more. When the types match, the `==` and `===` are identical, but when they don't match, the `==` does further type analysis to see if the operands can be converted to matching types, and recursively enters the algorithm until matching types are found and the values compared.

Comment: *"To determine if arrays are equal, you have to perform type conversion to a string."* You don't have to, and in fact it's an unreliable way of comparing: `String([1,2]) == String(["1,2"]); // true`